# Stripping characters from a Bash variable

Tags: bash

I am attempting to write a bash script (poorly) and need assistance in stripping characters from a variable.

variable is defined as `$managementipmask= 111.111.111.111/24`

I need to strip the /24 from the end of the variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$managementipmask= 111.111.111.111/24` is absolutely wrong in Bash. No spaces around `=` and no leading `$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parameter expansion to remove everything from the first `/`:

```
$ k="111.111.111.111/24"
$ echo "${k%%/*}"
111.111.111.111
```

See this resource on parameter expansion for additional details:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion

> **${parameter%pattern}**
>
> The 'pattern' is matched against the end of 'parameter'. The result is
>   the expanded value of 'parameter' with the shortest match deleted.
>
> **${parameter%%pattern}**
>
> As above, but the longest match is deleted.

So you can delete from the last `/` using a single `%`:

```
$ k="111.111.111.111/24/23"
$ echo "${k%/*}"
111.111.111.111/24
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
k="111.111.111.111/24"
echo "${k/%\/24/}"
```

It replaces last `/24` with empty string.

[From Bash Manual:](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern
>   against its value is replaced with string. If pattern begins with ‘/’,
>   all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the
>   first match is replaced. If pattern begins with ‘#’, it must match at
>   the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins
>   with ‘%’, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.
>   If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following
>   pattern may be omitted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution operation is applied to
>   each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
>   list.